# PHP get mime_type not working

Tags: php, api

I am attempting to use the virustotal API in order to upload a file to be scanned. However when I use the code from the API I receive error messages. 
The code being used is:

```
public function scanFile($filePath) {
        if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
            return array(
                    'response_code' => -4
                );
        }

        $realPath = realpath($filePath);

        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0) {
            $pathInfo = pathinfo($realPath);
            $fileName = $pathInfo['basename'];
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $parameters = array(
                    'file' => '@' . $realPath . ';' .
                    'type=' . finfo_file($finfo, $fileName) . ';' .         
                    'filename=' . $fileName
                );
        } else {
            // Due to a bug in some older curl versions
            // we only send the file without mime type or file name.
            $parameters = array(
                    'file' => '@' . $realPath
                );
        }

        return $this->_doCall(VirusTotalAPIV2::URL_SCAN_FILE, $parameters);
    }
```

And the error messages that are being returned are:

```
Warning: finfo_file(facebook.apk): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Android App Security\xampp\htdocs\androidapp\VirusTotalApiV2.php on line 48
stdClass Object ( [response_code] => 0 [verbose_msg] => Invalid submission format, the uploaded file must travel as a multipart MIME message, please review the documentation )
```

line 48 is this line:

```
'type=' . finfo_file($finfo, $fileName) . ';' .
```

I am really stumped and would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Read the docs. `finfo_file` 1st param takes a string, not a resource. Though, the code you've provided and the message you're getting don't seem to match up...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pass a basename for the second argument of finfo_file. That's why you have 'No such file' error, because this file is in another directory.

The solution is simply to use $realPath for finfo_file().

Comment: When I change: 
'type=' . finfo_file($finfo, $fileName) . ';' .   
to 
'type=' . finfo_file($finfo, $realPath) . ';' .
it comes up with 
Search: Facebook

path
-1
-1

Comment: Where do you get "Search: Facebook path -1 -1" ?

Comment: When I try to upload a file to the API using its path/filename/type and the result from that is path -1 -1. Facebook was just the name of the apk file that I was trying to scan with the API